# Deploying Rails app with docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, docker

Currently I have pretty standard env: nginx + web(Rails) + worker(Sidekiq) + Postgres + Redis + Data Containers(File storage and DB storage).

The deploy process looks pretty straightforward:
 - update source code;
 - rebuild container(s);
 - run migrations;
 - stop old and launch new containers;

For `web` (rails) and `data` (pg) containers it would be something like this:
`docker-compose build && docker-compose run web rake db:migrate && docker-compose up -d`.

Are there any best practices and is this solution compatible with them?
Capistrano uses releases approach (with ability to rollback) - is this approach applicable with Docker? Is it even possible to use Docker and Capistrano?

Please share your solutions or links to success stories.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get an answer for this from anywhere? I'd be interested in finding out.

Comment: No, sorry. 
Not the ruby user anymore as wel...