# Docker Compose + Rails: best practice to migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I just followed this article on [Running a Rails Development Environment in Docker](https://blog.codeship.com/running-rails-development-environment-docker/). Good article, works great. After setting everything up, I decided to go on and set up a production environment.

**GOAL:**

I want to `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` every time my docker image is run.

**PROBLEM:**

If I move the database creation and migrations steps...

```
docker-compose run app rake db:create
docker-compose run app rake db:migrate
```

...into the Dockerfile...

```
RUN rake db:create && rake db:migrate
```

...that will throw an error...

```
could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
```

...because the `host` in my `database.yml`...

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  host: postgres
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_five_development
```

...is set to the `postgres` service name specified in my `docker-compose.yml`...

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - "5432"
  app:
    build: .
    command: rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - postgres
```

...since that is the recommended practice as pointed by the article.

**QUESTION:**

How can I automatically `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` every time my docker image is run?

[I am trying to achieve the same thing as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419949/deploying-rails-app-with-docker-compose)

Answer (score 28):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd:

> If you would like your container to run the same executable every time, then you should consider using ENTRYPOINT in combination with CMD. See ENTRYPOINT

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

tl;dr

You could define an `entrypoint` under app and define a bash file there:

```
app:
  entrypoint: [bin/entry]
  ..
```

bin/entry file example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

rake db:create
rake db:migrate

exec "$@"
```

Comment: This answer works well on `docker-compose up --build` but when I try to do `docker-compose run web rake console`. It will throw a error. `database "yc_development" is being accessed by other user`

Answer (score 21):

This approach creates the database if the migration is not able to succeed. It also avoids the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732187/1935918) of being unable to start the server because a pid file was left behind. Create the file as `app/lib/docker-entrypoint.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732187/1935918
set -e

if [ -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm /app/tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle exec rake db:migrate 2>/dev/null || bundle exec rake db:setup

exec bundle exec "$@"
```

The docker-compose.yml then includes:

```
entrypoint: ["/app/lib/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
command: ["rails","server","-b","0.0.0.0","-p","3000"]
```

Comment: if migration fails for any reason the db will be rebuilt. Is it not dangerous?

Comment: @masciugo Valid point. Was you able to find a way to check if the db is already there?

Comment: Why do this over just running the command separately in a container?

Answer (score 3):

I use a Makefile:

```
run:
    docker-compose up -d \
    && docker-compose run web rake db:create
```

So, now when I wanna `docker-compose up` I just do `make run` instead.

Comment: how do you escape the colon?  I get the following `make: *** No rule to make target 'create', needed by 'run'.  Stop.`

Comment: you shouldn't need to worry about escaping any colons if format the Makefile correctly. try putting it all on one line `docker-compose up -d && docker-compose run web rake db:create` and make sure you use tabs (^I) and not spaces