# Docker, Rails, Postgres - db service not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /paper_scammer_docker
WORKDIR /paper_scammer_docker
COPY Gemfile /paper_scammer_docker/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /paper_scammer_docker/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /paper_scammer_docker

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/paper_scammer_docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - "db:db"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I am successfully able to build image using the following command

```
docker-compose build
```

If i do `docker-compose up` in project root directory my app runs fine and i can see two containers one for my rails app and other for postgres when i do `docker container ls`. I observed that postgres image is loaded from library.

database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  host: db
  username: postgres
  password:
  # user: gnpsllco_papaer
  # password: sharma@123

development:
  <<: *default
  database: paper_scammer_development
  # user: postgres
  # password: sharma@123

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: paper_scammer_test
  # user: postgres
  # password: sharma@123

production:
  <<: *default
  database: gnpsllco_paper_scammer
```

**Problem**

I run the following command to start docker container from the image of my rails app.

```
sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 paperscammer_web
```

postgres container is not running or missing.

I want to understand how this dockerfile-compose handle this, when i spin the image of rails app which says its depends in postgres service shouldn't it also spin a postgres container and set 'db' as host for connections.

or do it needs to be spinned manually for postgres.

I get the following error when i run http://localhost:3000

```
could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I can see postgres container is not running.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried specifying the port in database.yml file?  `port: 5432`

Comment: `You can see postgres container is not running`, why not `docker logs your_postgres_container` to find the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose up` and `docker run` are different commands. Using the latter one won't use the compose file, only the parameters passed to the command.

When you use `docker run` you must specify which containers you want to run specifically, if you want to run both `db` and `web` you should use this command twice.

In the other hand, when you use `docker-compose up` you run all the containers specified in `docker-compose.yml` with all its options.

Also, the `depends_on` property just specifies that the container `web` will be launched once the container `db` is successfuly launched.

As a final remark, if you want your containers to be able to communicate with each other you should add a network to the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - my-network-name

  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/paper_scammer_docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - "db:db"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - my-network-name

networks:
  my-network-name:
    driver: bridge
```

Also is a good practice to add a `container_name` for referencing them.

With thoose options now containers can communicate with their names as IPs/hostnames:

```
http://<container_name>:<port>
```

For example, the container `web` will be able to connect to the database in the `db` container like this:

```
http://db:5432/gnpsllco_paper_scammer
```

Notice the IP/hostname is now the name of the container.

As @LinSel pointed, you can build and run all the containers with the command (sudo is not needed):

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: but still i this uses source code to build image, i want to find solution for shared images.

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear, what do you mean by 'shared images'? Images that are published in Docker Hub?

Comment: after building the image this image will be registered with dockerhub and few tools work to pick image from dockerhub and spin AWS ECS

Comment: as you mentioned i have to run `docker run` twice, this works fine for me. I am now stuck with how to run database migrations as 'docker run paperscammer bundle exec rake db:migrate` only runs migrations and exit without starting the  container

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089999/docker-compose-rails-best-practice-to-migrate

Comment: Also I suggest to edit your question and make it more clear, adding what you said here in the comments, because this is the real problem.

Comment: yeah i will update and accept answer, just trying this one

Answer (score 3):

`sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 paperscammer_web` will start only the web server, you need to run `docker-compose` :

```
sudo docker-compose up -d --build
```

second option:

```
 sudo docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 -v ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:10
 sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 --link db:db -v .:/paper_scammer_docker paperscammer_web
```

Comment: yeah but how that scales when deploying in productions, docker-compose up looks for docker file, if you follow this https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/ . services defined in docker-compose file should put all the services as containers

Comment: with compose it works fine, but the rails applications image doesn't work fine when i run docker run -p 3000:3000 paperscammer_web. you must be aware docker compose will create image then start. but for production deployments output produced by docker compose build produce a image which will be used to spin containers.

Comment: yeah my app now able to connect to db service, but database is not created error comming this time

Comment: FATAL: database "paper_scammer_development" does not exist , docker run command is not running buundle exec rake db:create as mentioned in docker file

Comment: i think following this should help https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/. i have to add create database commands and skip it if database already exists. How you suggest? To have my own dockerfile to create postgres image.

Comment: your answer helped me running database service and creating links, but i can't hook database migrations yet with docker run command. running `sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 --link db:db paperscammer_web bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate` runs only migrations and exit without starting the container.

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean my DB image i am running the command `sudo docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 -v ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:10` just and postgres image is created. Again i don't think it will have anything to do with db image as rails migrations need to run when db image is spinnned in the container. i guess workaround is around my web_app image.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

> ./**Dockerfile**

```
ROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.2

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
      binutils-gold \
      build-base \
      curl \
      file \
      g++ \
      gcc \
      git \
      less \
      libstdc++ \
      libffi-dev \
      libc-dev \ 
      linux-headers \
      libxml2-dev \
      libxslt-dev \
      libgcrypt-dev \
      make \
      netcat-openbsd \
      nodejs \
      openssl \
      pkgconfig \
      postgresql-dev \
      python \
      tzdata \
      yarn 

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle check || bundle install 

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --check-files

COPY . ./

COPY ./sh/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

> ./**.env**

```
APP_NAME=api
APP_PORT=3100

DATABASE_NAME=rails_db
DATABASE_USER=batman
DATABASE_PASSWORD=super_pass_123
DATABASE_PORT=5342
DATABASE_HOST=api_db # must be equal to the name of the postgres service in docker-compose.yml
```

> ./**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  api: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}
    depends_on:     
      - api_db
    ports: 
      - "${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development

  api_db: # must be equal to `DATABASE_HOST ` in ./.env
    image: postgres
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=on -c log_destination=stderr -c log_directory=/logs -p ${DATABASE_PORT}
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log/db:/logs
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}

volumes:
  gem_cache:
  db_data:
  node_modules:
```

> ./sh/entrypoints/**docker-entrypoint.sh**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047028/4488252

```
DB_INITED=0
if db_version=$(bundle exec rake db:version 2>/dev/null)
then
    if [ "$db_version" = "Current version: 0" ]
    then
        echo "DB is empty"
    else
        echo "DB exists"
        DB_INITED=1
    fi
    bundle exec rake db:migrate 
else
    echo "DB does not exist"
    bundle exec rake db:setup
fi

if [ $DB_INITED == 0 ]
then
    echo "Performing initial configuration"
    # init some plugins, updated db if need, add initial data
fi
```

> ./config/**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT'] || '5432' %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

> ./**.dockerignore**

https://gist.github.com/neckhair/ace5d1679dd896b71403fda4bc217b9e

```
.git
.gitignore
README.md

#
# OS X
#
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride
# Icon must end with two \r
Icon
# Thumbnails
._*
# Files that might appear on external disk
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk

#
# Rails
#
.env
.env.sample
*.rbc
capybara-*.html
log
tmp
db/*.sqlite3
db/*.sqlite3-journal
public/system
coverage/
spec/tmp
**.orig

.bundle

.ruby-version
.ruby-gemset

.rvmrc

# if using bower-rails ignore default bower_components path bower.json files
vendor/assets/bower_components
*.bowerrc
bower.json
```

### Usage

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

build and run: `docker-compose up --build -d`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

stop: `docker-compose down`

stop + delete images and volumes: `docker-compose down --rmi all --volumes`